# Leetcode C Linked List Question: Why do I get Runtime Error: Member Access within misaligned address error depending on which ListNode* I return?

Tags: c, linked-list

While trying to solve Reverse Nodes in k-Group, I encountered the following error:

> Line 50: Char 17: runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0x00000000000a for type 'struct ListNode', which requires 8 byte alignment [solution.c]
> 0x00000000000a: note: pointer points here

The problem lies in my reverseFirstK function. Originally, I made it return newHead, as below:

```
struct ListNode* reverseFirstK(struct ListNode* head, struct ListNode* pre, int k) {
    struct ListNode* newHead;
    struct ListNode* next;
    struct ListNode* cur = head;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
        newHead = cur->next;
        next = cur->next->next;
        newHead->next = head;
        cur->next = next;
        head = newHead;
    }
    if (pre != NULL) {
        pre->next = newHead;
    }
    
    return newHead;
}
```

That leads to the error above. However, when I return head, as in below,

```
struct ListNode* reverseFirstK(struct ListNode* head, struct ListNode* pre, int k) {
    struct ListNode* newHead;
    struct ListNode* next;
    struct ListNode* cur = head;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
        newHead = cur->next;
        next = cur->next->next;
        newHead->next = head;
        cur->next = next;
        head = newHead;
    }
    if (pre != NULL) {
        pre->next = head;
    }
    
    return head;
}
```

The code works. I do not know why the error does not occur.

Full code for reference:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */

int atLeastKMore(struct ListNode* head, int k) {
    while (head != NULL && k > 0) {
        k--;
        head = head->next;
    }
    
    if (k == 0) return 1;
    return 0;
}

struct ListNode* reverseFirstK(struct ListNode* head, struct ListNode* pre, int k) {
    struct ListNode* newHead;
    struct ListNode* next;
    struct ListNode* cur = head;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
        newHead = cur->next;
        next = cur->next->next;
        newHead->next = head;
        cur->next = next;
        head = newHead;
    }
    if (pre != NULL) {
        pre->next = newHead;
    }
    
    return newHead;
}

struct ListNode* reverseKGroup(struct ListNode* head, int k) {
    struct ListNode* pre = NULL;
    struct ListNode* cur = head;
    int storeHead = 0;
    
    while (atLeastKMore(cur, k)) {
        struct ListNode* tmp = cur;
        cur = reverseFirstK(cur, pre, k);
        pre = tmp;
        if (storeHead == 0) head = cur;
        storeHead = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }
    
    return head;
}
```

Comment: The address of `0x00000000000a` is suspicious, it is probably a garbage value somewhere, possibly from an uninitialized variable. If you run your program under a tool like Valgrind, you will get error messages for uninitialized values. Alternatively, you could try initializing all of the local variables in your function. Note that if `k < 1` then `pre->next = newHead` will assign a garbage value to `pre->next`.

Comment: Your loop doesn't stop if it reaches the end of the list.

Comment: I cannot see anything obviously wrong as long as `reverseFirstK` is only called if `atLeastKMore` returns true (for the same `k`).